# "Search for files on this computer" application is missing

Tags: unity, search

Having upgraded to (trusty) 14.04, I am unable to find the 'find files with a name containing...' application contained in the previous version (and which I found extremely useful). Where is it???

Answer (score 0):

Try;

apt-get install gnome-search-tool

This is a general purpose, gui-based, file searching application for Ubuntu, also available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the filing cabinet icon.

Click on the magnifying glass.

Type "some text".

This should pull up files and directories that contain "some text"

"some text" = the thing you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks.  This definitely works for files & directories in my 'Home' folder.

Comment: But: The previous 'magnifying glass' tool allowed you to search in other places like 'Desktop' - I don't see how to do this.